# Python to C# code

Tags: c#, python, .net

I'm trying to convert a piece of Python code to C#, but unfortunately I'm stuck on a certain piece of code. I hope someone is able to assist me resolving my problem.

The Python function:

```
    def get_senteces_ranks(self, content):

    # Split the content into sentences
    sentences = self.split_content_to_sentences(content)

    # Calculate the intersection of every two sentences
    n = len(sentences)
    values = [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            values[i][j] = self.sentences_intersection(sentences[i], sentences[j])

    # Build the sentences dictionary
    # The score of a sentences is the sum of all its intersection
    sentences_dic = {}
    for i in range(0, n):
        score = 0
        for j in range(0, n):
            if i == j:
                continue
            score += values[i][j]
        sentences_dic[self.format_sentence(sentences[i])] = score
    return sentences_dic
```

Basically I would like to convert the whole function to C#, but I'm mostly stuck on the following code:

```
        n = len(sentences)
    values = [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            values[i][j] = self.sentences_intersection(sentences[i], sentences[j])
```

I translated this to the following C# code, but it's incorrect.. if N is 5 it should give me: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] but the C# code gives me [0,0] due to the first line..

```
            double[,] array = new double[length, length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j)
                array[i, j] = sentences_intersection(sentences[i], sentences[j]);
```

How can I port this piece of code successfully?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code translation service which SO doesn't provide

Comment: Where should one look for code translation - whether that be questions or software? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you are incrementing `i` and `j` **before** they are first used, so you will in reality only be in the loop for values 1 through `length-1` when you want to be from 0 to `length-1`. Change it to this:

```
double[,] array = new double[length, length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = sentences_intersection(sentences[i], sentences[j]);
    }
}
```

I added brackets around the two loops out of personal preference

Comment: I don't think it matters whether he uses `i++` or `++i` in his loops. Either way, `i` won't increment until after going through the loop once.

Comment: The problem I'm having relies in the double[,] array = new double[length, length];

This outputs always in a 2 dimensional array, where the code: [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)] turns into a N dimensional array